# SASS function darken & lighten not working when using object of colors

Tags: sass

I am trying to use the `darken` sass function but when I read from the sass object in my scss module, it thinks the color is actually a string and thus the function fails to parse the variable passed in.

**variables.scss**

```
$primary: #ae9fec;
$secondary: #d19ac1;

$theme: (
    "primary": ($primary, white),
    "secondary": ($secondary, white)
);
```

**Button.module.scss**

```
@each $colorGroup in $theme {
    &[data-variant="#{nth($colorGroup, 1)}"] {
        background-color: #{nth(nth($colorGroup, 2), 1)}); // this works

        &:hover {
            background-color: darken(#{nth(nth($colorGroup, 2), 1)}), 10%); // this does not because it thinks its a string.  I tried unquote() but that didn't work, still thinks it's a string.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have some extra parentheses. I cleaned your code up, and here is a version that also tests for the value you are passing to `darken()`. I hope you can take it from here:
https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7418bdf5914e947a9d00fb798cc731e0

Comment: @ShawnSpencer OP is aware of what you're stating (indicated by his comment in his loop stating verbatim the culprit) but he's asking how to remedy it by converting the value from string to color. Which in light of trying a couple tries on my own and not getting it I'd be interested in knowing too, though you were right about the original syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the interpolation in your selector rules (not the selector itself), it should compile as intended.

Here's a test - and I'm assuming you are nesting the `@each` loop inside a selector or using `@at-root`, since base-level rules cannot contain the `&` character like this - with a `.button` selector for your ruleset:

```
/* variables.scss */
$primary: #ae9fec;
$secondary: #d19ac1;

$theme: (
    "primary": ($primary, white),
    "secondary": ($secondary, white)
);

/* Button.module.scss */
.button {
    @each $colorGroup in $theme {
        &[data-variant="#{nth($colorGroup, 1)}"] {
            background-color: nth(nth($colorGroup, 2), 1);

            &:hover {
                background-color: darken(nth(nth($colorGroup, 2), 1), 10%);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiled code looks like this:

```css
.button[data-variant="primary"] {
  background-color: #ae9fec;
}

.button[data-variant="primary"]:hover {
  background-color: #8a74e4; /* Darkened $primary */
}

.button[data-variant="secondary"] {
  background-color: #d19ac1;
}

.button[data-variant="secondary"]:hover {
  background-color: #c177ab; /* Darkened $secondary */
}
```

I also removed the extra parenthesis in the example.

Comment: Considering I didn't even for whatever reason think to just remove the damn interpolation in the first place +1 :D

Comment: Same here - the unnecessary interpolation was rendering the value as a string. Removing that fixed my issue. Thanks!